# Splitview Controller 

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there a way out or can anyone point me to a link, I am looking out for changing the contents of RootViewController in a SPLITVIEW of IPAD upon selection of any button in detailViewController ?

Comment: Did any of our answers below helped? Please mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SplitViewController's content could be changed like this:

```
UISplitViewController * splitViewController  = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewControllerLeft, viewControllerRight, nil];


// the other stuff

// change left part of view controller
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newViewController, viewControllerRight, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the VC at index 0 of the UISplitViewController's viewControllers property. Try something like-

```
-(void) buttonPressed: (id)sender
{
      NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:splitVC.viewControllers];
      [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:myReplacementVC]; //index 0 corresponds to the left VC
      splitVC.viewControllers = arr;
      [arr release];
}
```

HTH,

Akshay